# Not able to Preview / Download files which are greater than 1.5 MB

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to preview or download the file which is greater than 1.5 MB and has taken as an input from code.

I have tried with less that 1.5 MB files and those are working fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state={
    previewData:''
  }

  InstructionHandler = (e) => {

    let files = e.target.files;
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.setState({ previewData: e.target.result });
      }}
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
       <input id="upload-instructions" type="file" name="Instruction-data" class="input-hidden" onChange={(e) => this.InstructionHandler(e)} value='' accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx,.pptx,.xlsx,.xls" />

<iframe class="mt-20" src={this.state.previewData}></iframe>
<a download="instructions" href={this.state.previewData}>Download Instructions</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Expections : I should be able to preview/download files which are greater than 1.5 MB.

Comment: Can you provide the React component. Based on what you've given us it's hard to tell you're even using React.

Comment: I have updated full code, from which u'll get an idea. Try uploading image files smaller than 1.5 MB and Greater than 1.5 MB

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here. `e.target.result` is the files text. The `src` attribute on `iframe` is a url that points to another document. What are you anticipating `this.state.previewData` to be? A url?

Comment: When you say "I can't preview/upload files larger than 1.5mb", what are you seeing that makes you think you can't upload? In `reader.onload` if you console log the result what do you see?

Comment: Yes, this.state.previewData should be an url to open it in iFrame.

Comment: Forget about the iFrame .
Just check - 
<a download="instructions" href={this.state.previewData}>Download Instructions</a>

I am using anchor tag to open that file in browser. The same is working for files less than 1.5 MB and not for >1.5 MB -- Please suggest.